# Find bitmap boundaries

Tags: algorithm

In a NxN array of bool values that represents a bitmap of a monochrome image, I need to find its rectangular boundaries (TopLeft, TopRight, BottomLeft, BottomRight coordinates). There is only one "image" in that NxN array and it's "continuous" - every next pixel is located at x+1 or x-1 or y+1 or y-1 relative to its neighbor.

The simplest algorithm I came up with is just to find first (upper-left) pixel (x,y) and then recursively probe four adjacent pixels (x+1, y), (x-1, y), (x, y+1), (x, y-1) and advance if any found..

Can you suggest something more efficient?

[EDIT] I'm looking for an algorithm that would be more efficient that a full scan. I.e. the boundary should be found with a minimal number of steps.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand the problem statement. It sounds like you just need to find the minimum and maximum row-numbers and column-numbers among true-valued array elements?

Comment: [Converting bitmap objects to polygons](https://www.google.com/patents/US6639593) expires soon.

Comment: If you mean bounding rectangle of image then a single parse of bitmap from left to right - top to botttom manner will suffice. Just keep noting `xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax` and use the same to create `TopLeft, TopRight, BottomLeft, BottomRight coordinates`

Comment: I'm looking for an algorithm that would be more efficient that a full scan.

Comment: Is the shape of the image known to be convex?

Comment: There is no such knowledge